# Converting milliseconds to Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I am using System.currentTimeMillis() and adding the value of a day/week/month based on user input. How can I convert this to java.sql.Timestamp so I can save it in mysql? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use constructor.

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp(long)

Comment: +1 - Yes.... however, note that depending on context this makes testing very difficult (it links your code to the time of the machine/vm).  This is one of the reasons I prefer [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - it provides a [utility class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html) that allows you to stop/offset/whatever the clock.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse personally I would do without java to insert current time to MySql. Just use NOW() function OR CURRENT_TIMESTAMP MySql expression (if the time zone of the java program is not important of course).

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is used to convert timestamp in milliseconds to Unix based java.sql.Timestamp

```
/**
     * Convert the epoch time to TimeStamp
     * 
     * @param timestampInString timestamp as string
     * @return date as timestamp
     */
    public static Timestamp getTimestamp(String timestampInString) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(timestampInString) && timestampInString != null) {
            Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestampInString));
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
            String formatted = format.format(date);
            Timestamp timeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(formatted);
            return timeStamp;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```